# Filtering Object having a null property along with Objects with non-null property matching certain criteria without getting NPE

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a list of objects `List<Objs>`.

Each object has a property `objId` of type `String` which can be initialized with a comma-separated string like `"1,2,3"`.

And I have a string array `sections` containing comma-separated strings like `"2,4"`.

I'm splitting those strings using `split(',')` into arrays and then performing comparison for each element (e.g. `"1,2"` -> `{"1,","2"}`).

I'm trying to collect all the objects which are either match `StringUtils.isEmpty(object.getObjId)` or their `objId` match one of the `sections` values.

*That is the desired behavior depending on the value of `objId`:*

*Case:1* `objId` = `"1,2,3"` and `sections` = `"2,4"`, as long as both have one value match "2", hence object should be included into the list.

*Case:2* `objId` = `"1,3"` and `sections` = `"2"`, since both don't have match value and hence object should **not** be included into the list.

*Case:3* `objId` = `null` || `""`  and doesn't matter what `sections` = `"{any}"` (meaning the contents of `sections` doesn't matter), the object should be included into the list.

*Case:4* `sections` = `null` || `""`, only object having `objId` = `null` || `""` should be included into the list.

The sample code below always returns me a `NullPointerException`. Could someone help to correct me?

*My code:*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TestStream {

    private List<Objs> getData() {
        List<Objs> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        Objs objs1 = new Objs();
        Objs objs2 = new Objs();
        Objs objs3 = new Objs();
        Objs objs4 = new Objs();
        objs1.setObjId("1,2,3");
        objects.add(objs1);
        objs1.setObjId("4,5,6");
        objects.add(objs2);
        objs2.setObjId("7,84,3");
        objects.add(objs3);
        objs3.setObjId(null);
        objects.add(objs4);
        return objects;
    }
    private List<Objs> test () {
        String[] sections = "2,8".split(",");
        List<Objs> objects = getData();
        List<Objs> result = objects.stream()
            .filter(object ->  object.getObjId() == null)
            .filter(object -> Arrays.stream(sections).anyMatch(object.getObjId()::contains))
            .skip(0)
            .limit(2)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestStream testStream= new TestStream();
        List<Objs> result = testStream.test();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.toArray()));
    }

    class Objs {
        private String objId;
        public void setObjId(String id) { objId = id;}
        public String getObjId() { return objId;}
    }
}
```

The `skip` and `limit` is for paging, currently I set it to skip `0` and limit for each page is `3` which means I am trying to retrieve the first page, each page can only have `3` items.

Comment: The structure of your objects in not clear. There's no sample data, `objId = "1,2,3" and sections="2,4"` - what does that mean, the two properties of a single object? No clue.  Or what does `sections="{any}"` means? And it's also impossible to say whether the logic of your stream is correct because (for instance, it is not clear if it's correct to apply `skip` after filters or not). Please provide the code (with a sample data in the code) that compiles, so that everyone can copy it and reproduce your problem. [*see - MRE*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: objId and sections are both comma separated string type. They both can be split(',') into arrays separated by the comma and then do the comparison (e.g. "1,2" -> {"1,","2"}. Certainly if it doesn't have to split and can do the comparison would be much easier. sections="{any}" means the value can be anything which doesn't care. It is similar to a Junit syntax.

Comment: That's the main purpose is to have the filtering get done first then do the **skip** operation.

Comment: Please [*update the question*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72908774/edit) instead of posting clarifications in the comments. Can you give the **complete runnable code** that anyone can copy-past in the IDE? Simply help others to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a fully executable program, but not sure why I still not getting the correct answer that I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NullPointerException` is being produced in the nested stream created inside the second `filter`:

```
.filter(object -> Arrays.stream(sections).anyMatch(object.getObjId()::contains))
```

It occurs while attempting to invoke method `contains` on the property of your object retrieved by `getObjId()` and `objId` happens to be `null`.

Why `getObjId()` returns `null` ? There's an object in your sample data which has this field set to `null` and in the first `filter` you're specifically telling that you want to retain in the stream pipeline only those objects whose `objId` is `null`:

```
filter(object -> object.getObjId() == null)
```

You might have a misconception on how `filter` works, it will retain in the stream only those elements for which the *predicate* passed to the *filter* would be evaluated to `true`, not the opposite.

Here is a quote from the [*documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that **match the given predicate**.

You can to change the predicate in the first filter to `object.getObjId() != null`, but that can lead to incorrect results  because *Case 3* of your requirements will not be fulfilled.

> *Case:3* `objId` = `null` || `""`  and doesn't matter what `sections` = `"{any}"` (meaning the contents of `sections` doesn't matter), the object should be included into the list.

If filter out only objects having non-null id, then we will lose the objects with id `null` (if any), and empty string id also might not pass the criteria. Otherwise, if we would not apply any filtering before accessing id, it will result in getting `NullPointerException`.

*Conclusion:* to retain objects having id equal to `null` and to an empty string and also objects having id matching to one of the strings in the sections array, we can not use two separate filters.

Instead, we need to we need to combine these filters in a single filter.

To simplify the code, we can define two *predicates*. One as `static` field for checking if the id is `null` or an empty a string. Another as a local variable because it'll depend on the sections array.

That's how it might look like (the full code provided in the link below):

```
public static final Predicate<Objs> IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY =
     object -> object.getObjId() == null || object.getObjId().isEmpty();
```

```
private List<Objs> test(String section) {
    String[] sections = section.split(",");
    List<Objs> objects = getData();
    
    Predicate<Objs> hasMatchingSection =
        object -> Arrays.stream(sections).anyMatch(object.getObjId()::contains);
    
    return objects.stream()
        .filter(IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY.or(hasMatchingSection))
        .limit(2)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I didn't apply `skip()` because it doesn't make sense skipping `0` elements.

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/t7X)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. However, I get all the following bold with undefined methods even I am using Java 8. Not Sure what I made wrong.     List<Objs> result = objects.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
        object -> **object.getObjId()** == null || **object.getObjId()**.isEmpty(),
        **Collectors.filtering**(object -> **object.getObjId()** == null || **object.getObjId()**.isEmpty() ||
            Arrays.stream(sections).anyMatch(**object.getObjId()**::contains),

Comment: @pintekus Solution above will work with Java 9 + because `Collectors.filtering()` was introduced with Java 9. While posting a question you have to specify all the detail that are relevant to the problem, version of JDK you're using is an **important** detail.

Comment: @pintekus Java 8 was realized roughly 10 years ago (that's a lot). I can show how to re-implement this solution with Java 8 if you really want (it'll be much tougher). But firstly, may I have your honest answer: is it part of a simplified legacy code that you have to maintain as a part of your work, or it's your pat-project which you've created as an exercise? In the first case my suggestion would be to implement this conditional logic with loop (the code would be much simpler and easier to read), in the second - simply download the latest version of long-term support version - which is JDK 17

Comment: Apologize on forgetting to mention the version. Currently we can only support Java 8 and that is the former case that I don't think can make user of JDK17. I don't mind if it is much tougher to read, but if a good possible solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pintekus I've managed to simplify the code. It works fine with JDK 8.